# function to submit forms one after the other

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, callback

Can someone help me please.

I have the following (simplified) code.

```
function save_all_des(){
    document.getElementById("form_zoom1").submit();
    document.getElementById("form_zoom2").submit();
}
```

I am submitting two forms, which have input of the same names but with different values.  Individually they submit ok. Also in IE9 they submit correctly when called as shown.  However in FF only the second works.

It appears that the second is submitting over the first.  I've tried using separate functions but they too seem to run at the same time. How do I make sure the code behind the form submittal is fininshed before the second submission?  I have used jquery a little but I don't know how to use callback and ajax (yet).

Any help appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: This isn't jquery, this is just plain vanilla javascript. Do you want to use jquery?

Comment: Hi I'm open to any suggstion as to how I can get around this issue so if there's a jquery solution then yes..  If you think the inclusion of the jquery tag is out of place I'll remove it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found an article relating to you problem: [Article](http://www.webdeveloper.com/forum/showthread.php?t=100425):

> it is possible to submit multiple forms, as long as the target for each form is different

I have not tested this tho.

Comment: THanks Steve.  These form have the same target unfortunately.  I'll see if I can change the code thought.

Comment: Is it not possible to use an Ajax request?

Comment: I'm new to Ajax I'm afraid.  I tried it with another issue a few weeks back and found problems with it only working only on the first call in IE but was fine elsewhere.  Is the a simple routine to do what I'm after?

Comment: Steve, the target approach seems to work!  However, I'm trying to find a javascript/jquery solution because for every new target I need to creat a new hidden iframe....

Comment: Is this asp or php or ... 
you can use this (http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) to send requests to the server.

Answer (score 0):

The jquery way would look like this:

```
$('#id-of-mouseover-object').mouseover (function () {
    $('#form_zoom1').submit(function() {
        $('#form_zoom2').submit ();
    });
});
```

Referenced from the [jquery docs](http://api.jquery.com/submit/).

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  The submission of the forms are triggered by a mouseover event which calls the function.  I've tried your suggestion but I'm probably incorporating it incorrectly.  How should I do it?

Comment: I just edited my answer to use the mouseover function as well. http://api.jquery.com/mouseover/

Comment: Hi.  How is this event activated? Does there need to be a listener or something?  I've removed the onmouseover="..." on the image as I presume it isn't necessary for the solution you prosed so I'm not sure how it fires? Can you help please?

Comment: That is the listener registration function for a mouseover event. Yes you don't need the onmouseover="..." Make sure the id of the img tag matches like this: $('#id-of-img').mouseover....

Comment: Hi, I can't get it to activate.  I've checked the jquery docs to ensure my code is right and even removed the body of your code and replaced with a simple alert but it doesn't come up.  I've got plenty of working jquery in the page but this is baffling me. Any ideas why it would fire up?

Comment: The page with this on has about 2500 line of code so it might not be practicable.  Besides, I've not encountered jsfiddle before.